# How can I detect when a MenuButton open its menu in Javafx?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

As there is not an OnShowing event in this control (at least in Javafx 2.2), and there is no way to access the underlying menu control,  I find no way to populate dynamic menu items here.

I tried using the OnAction event, but it doesn't fire.

I tried using the OnShowing event of the menu inside the MenuButton that contains the dynamic choices, but that doesn't fire either.

There must be some way, but I can't think of any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding dynamic menu items on showing can be this way:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final MenuButton m = new MenuButton("Cities");
    m.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem("Moscow"), new MenuItem("Bishkek"), new MenuItem("Istanbul"));
    m.showingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if(newValue) {
                m.getItems().add(new MenuItem("new city item"));
            }
        }
    });

    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    stackPane.getChildren().add(m);
    Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works!  Thank you very much.  Maybe they decide to have a setOnShowing method in the future that is easier to find, but this solution works well for now.  Thank you.